# How to debug why my Unity3D game does not increase score?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, singleton, instance, destroy

I'm doing some practice with Unity. What I'm basically trying to do is by using the singleton design pattern from the gameManager script. I want to prompt the player to hit space, causing score to increase after each time, health to decrease after each time, and money increase once health reaches 0 and the cube is destroyed. I think I got some script assignments mixed up or I'm not sure how to reference the right game object. For whatever reason, hitting space won't increase score or decrease health.

I got 3 texts: score, health, and money, along with a cube in the middle of the scene, with the script, DestroyBySpace, assigned to it.

I have a gameManager empty object assigned to the gameManager script

Here's the script for Game Manager:

```
private int currentScore;
private int currentHealth;
private int currentMoney;

public Text scoreText;
public Text healthText;
public Text moneyText;

public static GameManager instance;

void Start()
{
    currentScore = 0;
    currentHealth = 20;
    currentMoney = 0;
    updateScore();
    updateMoney();
    updateHealth();
}

void Awake()
{
    instance = this;
}

public void adjustScore(int newScore)
{
    currentScore += newScore;
    updateScore();
}

public void adjustHealthAndMoney(int newHealth, int newMoney)
{
    currentHealth -= newHealth;
    updateHealth();

    if (currentHealth == 0)
    {          
        currentMoney += newMoney;
        updateMoney();
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

void updateScore()
{
    scoreText.text = "Score: " + currentScore;
}

void updateHealth()
{
    healthText.text = "Health: " + currentHealth;
}

void updateMoney()
{
    moneyText.text = "Money: " + currentMoney;
}
```

and here's my script for DestroyBySpace:

```
public int scoreValue;
public int healthValue;
public int moneyValue;
public GameObject target;
public GameManager gameManager;

void Start()
{
    GameObject gameManagerObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("GameManager");

    if (gameManagerObject != null)
    {
        gameManager = gameManagerObject.GetComponent<GameManager>();
    }

    if (gameManager == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Cannot find Game Manager script");
    }
}

void onTriggerEnter()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        GameManager.instance.adjustHealthAndMoney(healthValue,moneyValue);
        GameManager.instance.adjustScore(scoreValue);
    }
}
```

If you could help steer me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've mixed up what the monobehavior `onTriggerEnter()` does.

`onTriggerEnter()` is called when another GameObject enters the collider of the GameObject the script is attached to. This is not the place to check for keyboard presses.

What you probably want to use is the `Update()` monobehavior. It runs every frame, so you are guaranteed that if the user presses a key the function will be able to see it.

Your code would look something like this:

```
void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        GameManager.instance.adjustHealthAndMoney(healthValue,moneyValue);
        GameManager.instance.adjustScore(scoreValue);
    }
}
```

Also, I think you misunderstood what `gameObject` refers to when you did `Destroy(gameObject)` in the `gameManager` script. `gameObject` refers to the gameObject the script it's mentioned in is attached to. This means when you do `Destroy(gameObject)` in the `gameManager` script you are destroying the object that the `gameManager` script it attached to.

To get rid of the GameObject called target you need to get access to it. You can do that in a couple ways:

1) Destroy(GameObject.Find("target"));

This directly searches for a GameObject called "target" and destroys it. The downside to this is that it requires the GameObject to be called exactly "target" and if there are multiple GameObjects called "target" it will only destroy the first one.

2) Create a public variable (like `public GameObject target`) and store the physical instance of the target in it through the inspector. Then when you want to destroy it, just do `Destroy(target)`;

This is how I would most likely do it.

Comment: It Works. Plus I was able to reset health once it reaches 0, but soon enough, I end up destroying game manager. How do I destroy the target?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by destroy the target. Also, all a singleton does is ensures that there is only one instance of the script active at any time. When you run `Destroy(gameObject)` you are destroying the only instance of the script that exists, so there won't be an instance of it anymore. The singleton ensures that if you initialize another gameObject with the script attached to it, that instance of the script will be the only instance of the script.

Comment: I was trying to destroy a cube in the scene view named target that I assigned DestroyBySpace

Comment: ohhh... That's an easy one. The object `gameObject` refers to the gameObject the script you are in is attached to. Since you use `Destroy(gameObject)` in the `gameManager` script, it destroys the GameObject the `gameManager` script is attached to. To destroy the GameObject called target you need to Destroy that GameObject. One way you can do this is by doing `Destroy(GameObject.Find("target")`. Keep in mind though, this depends on the name of the GameObject being exactly "target". Another thing you can do is create a public variable in gameManager and set it to the target, and then destroy it.

Comment: I'll try that. I'll work to expand on this project, and I'll ask more questions when I get to it. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: No problem! Also if you have other questions that aren't related directly to the question you had here, ask it as another question on stack overflow and then tell me about the question here. People don't like it when you add unrelated questions to your current question.

Comment: @user8048595 If this answer solved your problem just accept it then ask a new question for your non related issues. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) post for how to do that.